# How to capture or recognize touch actions in mobile web browser(chrome) using Appium?

Tags: java, xpath, appium

I want to save the xpath of each actions(pinch, flick, tap, etc.) that we are doing in mobile web browser. How to capture those actions?

So that I can play the same with recorded or captured data.

Comment: Selenium has nothing to do with Mobile Web Browsers, We do have Appium for Mobile Automation.

Comment: yes. your correct. I want to store the data that we are performing different actions(tap,finch,flick etc...) in mobile web browser.

For ex: if i tap on any button or anything in mobile web browser(www.google.com) i want to capture those elements. Is any listeners available